# Not copying the values properly

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with my macro to copy paste only the values of the range `A6:AM46,A52:AM84` to `AN6` location on the same sheet.

```
 Sub PréparerGrilles()


    Range("A6:AM46,A52:AM84").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Range("AN6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

I get the 1004 error (multiple selection error) 
Could you help me with this ?

Comment: Why does your code use "A6:AL46,A52:AM84" when your question says "A6:AM84"?   You can't copy multiple selections if they have different row and column widths.

Comment: Range("A6:AM84") gives me the same problem...

Comment: (a) Using `Range("A6:AL46,A52:AM84")` would give you a `This command cannot be used on multiple selections` error.  Using `Range("A6:AM84")` would give you a `Paste method of Worksheet class failed` error.  That is not the same problem.  (b) So that we can provide an answer, which range(s) are you **actually** trying to copy?

Comment: Sorry I edited the question... I am trying to copy the A6:AM46, A52:AM84 range.

Comment: And you **definitely** don't want `AM6:AM46` included?  (Code is a lot easier if the number of columns in the two areas are the same.)  Sigh - now your question has been edited to include the extra 41 cells.

Comment: Sorry about this misunderstanding , I have being cracking my head on this for hours... I want to copy the range A6:AM46 and the A52:AM84 range

Comment: And do you want them to go to `AN6:BZ46` and `AN52:BZ84`, or to `AN6:BZ79`?

Comment: AN6:BZ46 and AN52:BZ84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy **values** from `A6:AM46,A52:AM84` to `AN6:BZ46,AN52:BZ84` you can do the following:

```
Sub PreparerGrilles()
    Range("AN6:BZ46").Value = Range("A6:AM46").Value
    Range("AN52:BZ84").Value = Range("A52:AM84").Value
End Sub
```

---

Version using the `Range.Copy` method:

```
Sub PreparerGrilles()
    Range("A6:AM46").Copy Destination:=Range("AN6:BZ46")
    Range("A52:AM84").Copy Destination:=Range("AN52:BZ84")
    Range("AN6:BZ46").Value = Range("AN6:BZ46").Value
    Range("AN52:BZ84").Value = Range("AN52:BZ84").Value
End Sub
```

I recommend that you don't slow your code down by using this.  It will also lead to potentially incorrect values if your formulae refer to anything that wasn't part of the copy.

---

Version using a `PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` method:

```
Sub PreparerGrilles()
    Range("A6:AM46").Copy
    Range("AN6:BZ46").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("A52:AM84").Copy
    Range("AN52:BZ84").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

I **strongly** recommend against using this method, as it leads to too many "unreproducible" errors due to the users copying things via the clipboard between when your code does the Copy and when it does the Paste, and also because of the fact that your Copy zaps whatever the user might have manually pasted to the clipboard.

Comment: This works but I wanted to use the range copy method , thanks

Comment: @NicoCoallier Why do you want to use the `Range.Copy` method?  Is there a need to allow the users to accidentally copy something to the clipboard part way through your code to create a random bug effect into it?  Is there a need to make the code a bit slower for some reason?

Comment: @NicoCoallier What has that got to do with the `Range.Copy` method being used instead of a standard copy of values?

Comment: you are probably right.... I am quite new to VBA , I guess I was just a bit hard headed ! Thanks for your code !

Comment: @NicoCoallier - I have updated the answer to show how to use a `Range.Copy` approach, and also a `Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` approach.  I very strongly urge you not to use either method.

Comment: @NicoCoallier - I worked out what you mean by a "switch" - you mean to allow the users to either copy the formulae or the values.  OK - I can see that being potentially useful.  In which case use the second of my three methods with an `If` around the two lines setting the values.  But you will need to ensure that the formulae being copied will continue working after being shifted 39 columns to the right.

Answer (score 1):

Application.CutCopyMode = False cleans the clipboard....

Better code for that is:

```
 Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("SOMMAIRE") 'this means it will only work on this sheet, you should change the name of the sheet or ask me what do you want in order to get it working on other sheets

    ws.Range("A6:AL46").Copy
    ws.Range("AN6").PasteSpecial xlValues

    ws.Range("A52:AM84").Copy
    ws.Range("AN52").PasteSpecial xlValues

 End Sub
```

Edited: Now that should do the trick. Try it out and tell me if it works

Edited2: This is what you want, at least for what you asked so far.

Comment: You can't copy a 41 x 38 range and a 33 x 39 range at one time.  (You **can** copy a 41 x 39 with a 33 x 39, and probably a 41 x 38 with a 41 x 39, but if both rows and columns are different then Excel doesn't like it.)

Comment: @NicoCoallier - You should include details about what error you are getting into your question - it stops people going down the wrong track in trying to solve your issue.  (But the clearing of the clipboard by setting `CutCopyMode` to False would cause you problems after you fixed the original error.)

Comment: True that... totally forgot about the multiple range, i usually do that on cells(row, column)

Comment: I've edited my answer check the new code if it works Nico Coallier

Comment: Still got the 1004 error with this part of the code :
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOMMAIRE").Range("A52:AM84").Copy Destination:= _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOMMAIRE").Range("AN" & LastRow + 1)

Comment: @NicoCoallier I'm sorry, but I'm not getting errors on my module from that line and i've filled a worksheet with data to test. Worked out all good.

Comment: FWIW - I can't see anything wrong with your code which would cause a 1004 error on that line.  (Unless, perhaps, one of the formulas doesn't work when copied across?  I'm not sure whether that would give a 1004 error though.)  @NicoCoallier - which 1004 error are you getting using Damian's code?

Comment: no more error ...maybe I didn't copy paste it properly......Still a problem it seem like the range A52:AM84 is copied over the copy of A6:AM46

Comment: Another problem is that this code copy the formula ...I just want to copy the cell values